# what is "Loading symbols" and why does it take so long the first time?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, web-applications

When I first execute my C# Web Application project from Visual Studio 2012, the first launch always takes quite a while, usually 20 to 30 seconds. Most of this time seems to be "Loading symbols for reference X.Y.Z.dll". Each of my around 30 references takes about a second to load these symbols. Once they've been loaded the first time, it usually only takes a few seconds for subsequent executions.

What is this "loading symbols", exactly? Why does it take so long? Is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: did you enable net source stepping or others related for debuggind net source

Comment: I enabled the web.config file for debugging when it first prompted me, but not any Dot.Net original source code. So I don't think I enabled net source skipping.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe you can disable it via

```
 Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols
 check Automatically load symbols
```

and

```
 Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General
 enabling "enable Just My code "
```

Comment: Does this have any adverse effects on speed or reliability of the web app?

Comment: for speed always use release mode, This  just affects debugging process ( not debug code)

Comment: Okay, that answers the 3rd question. What about the first 2? What is it and why does it take so long? I'm actually more interested in those 2 answers than how to speed it up.

Comment: What do you mean by "affects debugging process? Does it mean debugging happens slower, or in a different way?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs you are able to debug net sources,too . Well it  is loading symbols . loading can take much  cause of internet speed

Comment: @NateKerkhofs I think your problem is just this. But I can be wrong

Comment: I'm not just interested in how to fix it. I also want a better understanding of the underlying cause in order to improve my knowledge on C# and programming in general.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/349076/Know-Program-Database-file-PDB

Answer (score 1):

Check that cache folder for symbols are correct
Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols

In my case I had a folder path from my previous computer and the folder can't be created at this path, hence it was downloading all symbols each time. No errors though.

Answer (score 0):

This happens specially when you use NuGet in your project. In my case it was solved by selecting NuGet.org Symbol Server.
[image]
But it is important to Select one for symbol cache.